# Jquery toggle for table with multiple rows

Tags: jquery, html-table, toggle

I'm trying to show & hide rows of a table which works fine. But I would like that by clicking on the parent row only its child-rows are shown and not all rows.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".level-1").click(function(){
    
     var target = $(this).parent().children(".level-2");
    $(target).slideToggle("slow");

    });
});
```

```css
table tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
.level-2 {display:none;}
.level-1:hover{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <td width="200">c1</td>
      <td width="200"><b>c2</b></td>
        <td width="200"><b>c3</b></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
       <tr class="level-1">
           <td width="200"><b>Parent1</b></td>
      <td class="spalte_1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="spalte_2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
      <td>child1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
      <td>child2</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-1">
      <td><b>Parent2</b></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
      <td>child1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
      <td>child2</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
      <td>child3</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-1">
      <td><b>Parent3</b></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
      <td>child1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
      <td>child2</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Link to fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ge0j4La4/28/)
Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the jQuery's `nextUntil()` API

Replace the following line

```
var target = $(this).parent().children(".level-2");
```

with

```
var target = $(this).nextUntil(".level-1");
```